# How to use .unmask() function on MaskedInput jQuery app?

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

I try to use `.unmask()` function after `.blur()` (`jQuery`), but it did not worked.

Please help, this is my code:

```
$('.cnpj').focus(function()
{
    $(this).mask('99999999/9999-99');
})
.blur(function(e)
{
   if($(this).val().length == 0)
   {
        var mask = '99999999/9999-99';
        $(this).unmask(mask);
        $(this).val('CNPJ');
   }
});
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="cnpj" name="cnpj" class="cnpj empty entriesFormInput01" value="CNPJ" />
```

My goal is that when the user don't put any value in the input, the input return with the same `value='CNPJ'`, because I have a lot of input in the form and the label is the value, if the user focus in one input and leave, the input will be empty if no value and i want to, when he leaves the input without a value the first value came back again.

Comment: So which part isn't working - the unmasking or the default value when empty on blur?

Comment: the unmask(), because if I try without it, the script work fine and the condition of length == 0 return to the input the value 'CNPJ' $(this).val('CNPJ');
so, its the plugin. if you want ai put the code online. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think that jQuery mask() function doesn't exists as default. There is an plugin for jQuery which can be used like that, is that right? I've found [this plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/). I think your code didn't worked because you didn't load this plugin or another one.

```
$('.cnpj').focus(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'CNPJ') 
       $(this).val('');
    //$(this).mask('99999999/9999-99');
}).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val().length == 0)
    {
        //var mask = '99999999/9999-99';
        //$(this).unmask(mask);
        $(this).val('CNPJ');
     }
});
```

Comment: Matei Mihai I load the plugin with the jquery.js, the function focus() and blur() are working, but i cant pass the value CNPJ came back when the validation length its equal 0, so when the script execute this validation i have to unmask() it, to return the default value thats 'CNPJ', and the problem is in the plugin, because if I try without it, the function $(this).val('CNPJ');
works fine.

Comment: $('.empty').focus(function(){ 
                var val = $(this).attr('title');
                var valAtual = $(this).val();
                if(val == valAtual){
                    $(this).val('');
                } else {
                    
                }    
            });
            
            $('.empty').hover(function(){
                var val = $(this).attr('title');
                var valAtual = $(this).val();
                if(valAtual == ''){
                    $(this).val(val);
                }
            });